# CSS: how to control size of SVG in page footer

Tags: css, svg

I am new to CSS an have inherited the following code that adds a page footer to the printed document

```
@page {
  @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) "("counter(pages)")";
    border-top:1mm #00a7d1 solid;
    width:100%;
  }

  @bottom-left {
    content: url(logo.jpg);
  }
}
```

I want to change `logo.jpg` to be an SVG image. Simply changing the URL works but the resulting graphic spans the entire width of the page.

In another part of the stylesheet the size of an SVG can be controlled like this:

```
#logo {
  position:absolute;
  height:auto;
  width:52mm;
}
```

However, setting values for `width` or `height` inside `@bottom-left` has no effect. How can I control the size of the SVG from within the `@page` rule?

---

**Edit:**
Here's the `<svg>` root element

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="233.21152mm"
   height="72.102554mm"
   viewBox="0 0 826.34002 255.48149"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="logo.svg">
```

Comment: It's an exported svg from vectorgraphics program??? If you want a fixed size for your svg elements you can keep size when export the svg from illustrator for example unchecking the "flex" option

Comment: A lot depends on the content of the SVG. In particular the attributes in the root `<svg>` tag.  Can you link, or post the SVG file?

Comment: @DaniP yes it's a logo created in inkscape. It gets used in several places in different sizes.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau it's a company logo so I'd rather not post the entire file. I've updated my question with the root element.

Comment: Check out [css-tricks.com: How to Scale SVG](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)

Comment: @CBroe I came across that page when looking for answers, but I don't know how to adapt the examples to fit in with the `@page` rule in the code I have. As I said, I'm new to css

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly set the size in the [margin at-rule](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#at-page-rule).  It is determined by the configuration in the `@page`.  Though I haven't used the paged media rules, so I am not 100% sure on that.

However try changing the `width` and `height` in your SVG from their current fixed-size values ("233mm" etc)  to `"100%"`. It should allow the SVG logo to scale properly.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be a step in the right direction. The svg is now a more sensible size, however the `width` and `height` properties inside the at-rule do not seem to have an effect on the scaling. Rather, they appear to be acting on an invisible element above the svg or something - `width` has no effect and increasing `height` shifts the image downwards